# .local domain any possible ways in getting the extension

Tags: network, penetration-test, domain

I was recently working on Broken link Hijacking and found a link in a target which reflected on multiple pages. It was `portal.REDACTED.local` which was not accessible and returned response as bad host.

So I never saw a extension that has `.local` so I just want to know if there is any way to claim this extension. If yes can you please share how can I claim this extension.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot claim a `.local` domain. This is not a public top level domain but actually reserved for internal use. For more details see [the Wikipedia entry about this top level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local).